# How to develop Windows Mobile apps using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, directshow

Where can I find tutorials and other beginner-level learning material for developing Windows Mobile apps using C#?

Especially helpful would be information on DirectShow for Windows Mobile via C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to use Visual Studio.
MS releases a Windows Mobile SDK, that plugs into Visual Studio.
The SDK includes tools, libraries, docs, and sample code.
Available on the [WM Downloads page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264327.aspx).

On the [WM Developer Center page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx), you find other resources, like technical articles, walkthroughs, webcasts, and so on, related to WM development.  Some of it is introductory.